# How to prove :$\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}}} <3$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, real-numbers

In  fact initially I wanted to prove that
$$\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}}} <2$$

Which by the [accepted answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591546/proving-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-cdots-sqrtn-2) fails to be true.

> **@Barry Cipra** advised me to ask this question in a different post:
> How can I now prove that:
> $$\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}}} <3$$

Note that the answers here do not provide an estimate of this sequence

Can anyone have any idea?

Comment: Did you check Masacroso's answer? It does prove the new identity ($e<3$).

Comment: Actually, the values of this is $2.7612068419574980332304546465801311048761259807153048509507‌​45961$, so even less than $\frac{70}{25}$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde thanks but in my numerics I need the smallest integer. that is why I persist with 2 or 3

Comment: @DietrichBurde my bad! When you skim too fast. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Well, it is indeed very similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472945/prove-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-cdots-sqrtn3-by-induction?noredirect=1&lq=1), so why not trying a similar induction.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde The limits for $n\to\infty$ coincide, the sequences don't.

Comment: @ProfessorVector For an induction to work, the sequences need not coincide. It may work just similarly.

Comment: The answer given here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472945/prove-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-cdots-sqrtn3-by-induction?noredirect=1&lq=1) as $n\to\infty$ solves your question completely because your series given in the answer here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591546/proving-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-cdots-sqrtn-2) is the same series.

Comment: I found an analytic upper bound of $4$.

Comment: @Masacroso Your are right but form the comments above the best integer is 3

Comment: @Masacroso For interest, what is your method of finding the bound of $4$?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire I write it as an answer (but it is not, properly speaking, an answer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For any $n > 0$, we have

$$s_n \stackrel{def}{=} \log\left(\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}}}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{\log(k!)}{2^k} = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{j=1}^k\log(j)
$$
Recall for any function $f(z)$ with power series representation $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty a_k z^k$,, the function
$\frac{f(z)}{1-z}$ has the power series representation $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty z^k \sum\limits_{j=0}^k a_j$. Apply this to the limit of $s_n$, we have

$$\begin{align}
s_\infty \stackrel{def}{=} \lim_{n\to\infty} s_n 
&=
\frac{1}{1 - \frac12} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\log k}{2^k}
= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log(k+1)}{2^k}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^k}\sum_{j=1}^k(\log(j+1)-\log(j))
= \frac{1}{1 - \frac12} \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log(k+1)-\log(k)}{2^k}\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\log\left(1+\frac1k\right)\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k2^{k-1}} + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\left[\log\left(1+\frac1k\right) - \frac1k\right]\\
&= 2\log(2) + \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\left[\log\left(1+\frac1k\right) - \frac1k\right]
\end{align}
$$
Notice $\log(1+x) \le x$ for all $x \in (-1,\infty)$, we can truncate the second series at some finite $p$ and turn it to an upper bound
$$
s_\infty \le 2\log(2) + \sum_{k=1}^p \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\left[\log\left(1+\frac1k\right) - \frac1k\right]$$
Take $p = 1$, this becomes $s_\infty \le 3\log(2) - 1$. As a result,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 
\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}}}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} e^{s_n} = e^{s_\infty} \le e^{3\log(2)-1} = \frac{8}{e} \approx 2.943035529371539 < 3$$

We can improve the bound by using a larger $p$. For example, if we take $p = 3$, we obtain a new bound $e^{s_\infty} \le 2.775306746902055$. This is within 1% of the correct limit $\approx 2.761206841957498$ pointed out by others in comment.

Comment: amazing... I tried to find some analytic bound but I failed miserably. Congrats!

Answer (score 13):

@BarryCipra has provided this limit [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2591546/proving-sqrt1-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-cdots-sqrtn-2): $$\log\left(\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{\ldots\sqrt{n!}}}}\right)\to\log1+{1\over2}\log2+{1\over4}\log3+{1\over8}\log4+\cdots$$ We can write the RHS as $$\frac12\log2+\frac14\log2+\frac14\log\frac32+\frac18\log2+\frac18\log\frac42+...$$ or $$\log2+\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n}\log\left(\frac{n+3}2\right)$$ since $\frac12+\frac14+\frac18+...=1$. Now as $$\log\left(\frac{n+3}2\right)<1.2^{n-2.39}$$ by [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/uqf72jiwir), $$\text{RHS}<\log2+\frac14\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1.2^{n-2.39}}{2^n}=\log2+\frac1{4\cdot1.2^{2.39}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty0.6^n$$ and by the geometric series with $a=1$ and $r=0.6$, $$\text{RHS}<\log2+\frac1{4\cdot1.2^{2.39}}\cdot2.5=1.097...$$ Hence $$\boxed{\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{\ldots\sqrt{n!}}}}<e^{1.097...}=2.996...<3}$$ as desired.

Answer (score 13):

For $n\geq 2$,
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}}} & = 2^{1/4+1/8+1/16+\ldots+1/2^n} \cdot 3^{1/8+1/16+1/32+\ldots+1/2^n}\cdot \ldots \cdot n^{1/2^n} \\
& < 2^{1/2}\cdot 3^{1/4} \cdot 4^{1/8} \cdot \ldots \cdot n^{1/2^{n-1}} \\
& = \sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n}}}} \\
&<3\end{align*}
The last inequality was proved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/472945/prove-sqrt2-sqrt3-sqrt-cdots-sqrtn3-by-induction).

Comment: THis inequality is somehow surprising. How the term with factorial be less than the  other?

Comment: I am pretty sure that we have$$
\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n}}}} < \sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{3!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{n!}}}}} $$ not the other way around.

Comment: @Sobolev Why do you think so? Which part of my proof is incorrect or unclear to you? I'll be glad to add some more explanation.

Comment: You should suppose $n\geq 2$.

Answer (score 3):

**SKETCH FOR AN ANALYTIC APPROXIMATION TO THE BOUND** (too long for a comment):

From [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2591590/173262) we have that

$$S_n:=\sqrt{1!\sqrt{2!\sqrt{\cdots\sqrt{\text{n}!}}}}=\exp\left(\sum_{j=1}^n\ln j\left(\frac1{2^{j-1}}-\frac1{2^n}\right)\right)\\=\exp\left(\left(\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{\ln (1+j)}{2^j}\right)-\frac{\ln(n!)}{2^n}\right)$$

And because $0\le\ln(n!)/2^n\le \ln(n^n)/2^n\le n^2/2^n$ then

$$S:=\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=\exp\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{\ln (k+1)}{2^k}\right)$$

Now using [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) and taking $\Delta g_k=(1/2)^k$ and $f_k=\ln(1+k)$ we find that $g_k=-(1/2)^{k-1}$, thus

$$\sum_{k\ge 0}\frac{\ln(1+k)}{2^k}=\left[-\frac{\ln(1+k)}{2^{k-1}}\right]_{k=0}^{k=\infty}+\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac12\right)^k\ln\left(1+\frac1{k+1}\right)\\=\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac12\right)^k\ln\left(1+\frac1{k+1}\right)=\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_{j\ge 1}\left(\frac12\right)^k(-1)^{j+1}\frac1{j(k+1)^j}\\\le\sum_{j= 1}^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}{j}\sum_{k\ge 0}\left(\frac12\right)^k\left(\frac1{1+k}\right)^j=2\sum_{j=1}^{2n+1}\frac{(-1)^{j+1}}j{\rm Li}_j(1/2)$$

for all $\in\Bbb N$, where ${\rm Li}_j$ is a [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm). Thus taking $n=0$ I found the upper bound of $4$.